# Intuition behind Cauchy's Formula for a Triangle

Tags: complex-analysis

I have been trying to understand the logic behind Cauchy's Formula for a Triangle (also called Goursat's lemma), which states:

For $T$ a triangle in $\Bbb{C}$ and $f$ a holomorphic function in an open set containing T and its interior, 
$$
\int_Tf(z)dz = 0
$$
I understand some examples where you can compute the whole integral and achieve the result, but I am having trouble with the intuition behind it. Could someone explain why this is true? Anything that I could visualize would help a lot as well.

Comment: The hard part with Goursat's lemma is to prove it without first assuming that $f'(z)$ is continuous. If you assume that, then you can apply Green's theorem since the differential $f(z)\,dz=f(x+iy)(dx+i\,dy)$ is closed.

Comment: Doesn't f being holomorphic in the set imply that it is continuous?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The intuition behind all of this is quite simple. It's the right concatenation of things:

1) You have that the $\mathbb{C}$ is a division ring so you can define a division. This seems a stupid thing to notice but it all begins there.

2)Since it's the division is defined (notice that is not the case for $\mathbb{R}^{2} $) you can define a much stricter sense of derivation (dividing by a complex number $h$ which is morally a 2D vector instead of considering the modulo as in normal $\mathbb{R}^{2} $ analysis), i.e.
$$f'\left(z\right)=\underset{{\scriptstyle h\longrightarrow0}}{lim}\frac{f\left(z+h\right)-f\left(z\right)}{h} $$
This much stricter condition leads to the fact that a function to be derivable must satisfy Cauchy-Riemann condition.

3)This Cauchy Riemann condition essentially says that the real part and the immaginary part of functions that are derivable in the Complex sense must be harmonic. A good way to cast the Cauchy Riemann condition is considering
$$ \frac{\partial f}{\partial\overline{z}}=0$$
where you intended the following meaning to this symbol
$$\frac{\partial}{\partial z}=\frac{1}{2}\left(\frac{\partial}{\partial x}-i\frac{\partial}{\partial y}\right),\,\,\,\,\,\frac{\partial}{\partial\bar{z}}=\frac{1}{2}\left(\frac{\partial}{\partial x}+i\frac{\partial}{\partial y}\right).$$

4) For harmonic function you have the Green Theorem saying that 
$$ \int_{\gamma}f\left(z\right)dz=i\int\int_{\Omega}\frac{\partial f}{\partial\overline{z}}dxdy,$$
But since $ \frac{\partial f}{\partial\overline{z}}=0$ are the Cauchy Riemann condition for differentiability and the function is differentiable there, you're done.
$$ \int_{\gamma}f\left(z\right)dz=0$$

5) You then have a lot of wonderful implication given by the simple fact that you can deform a path as much as you wish (as long you don't intersect the path or a singularity of the function) and the integral remains the same. And essentially everything in Complex Analysis remounts to this implication directly derived from the definition of complex derivative.